# Laravel Cartshopping for count and get total price increase by 1.21%

Tags: php, laravel

Very complex problem while I'm using `Gloudemans\Shoppingcart` all functions working fine except when I want to get the total price, I noticed that it increases by 1.21% !!!!

**controller**

```
public function edit($id)
{ 
    $product = Product::find($id);
    Cart::add($id, $product->product_title, 1, $product->product_price);
}
```

**blade**

```
<span>{{ Cart::total() }}</span>
```

Comment: You're going to need a bit more debugging here. Try `Log::info(Cart::content());` and then look in `/storage/logs/` for the details. This will dump all of the items in the cart, along with the prices. Make sure the quantity and the price for each look correct.

Comment: can you explain more how to use use Log::info(Cart::content());

Comment: `Log::info();` puts the requested information into the Laravel logs, which are usually stored in `storage/logs/`. `Cart::content()` is the content of your cart. It will list each item with its ID, Quantity, Price, Name, and any extra information you might store. You can also json_encode it like `Log::info(json_encode(Cart::content()));`, which would give something like this: `{"027c91341fd5cf4d2579b49c4b6a90da":{"rowid":"027c91341fd5cf4d2579b49c4b6a90da","id":1,"name":"My Product","qty":1,"price":5.99,"options":[],"subtotal":5.99}'`

Comment: From there, you can verify that the prices are correct for each item and make sure the math adds up correctly. If it doesn't, then track down what might be going on, such as logging the product information when you add it to the cart.

Comment: didn't get any thing as I added Log::info(json_encode(Cart::content())); into controller

Comment: Before or after the adding of the product?

Comment: I think the problem is coming form Tax Cart::tax()

Comment: to solve this problem just added {{(Cart::total())-(Cart::tax())}}

Comment: Or you could use `Cart::subtotal()` : `The subtotal() method can be used to get the total of all items in the cart, minus the total amount of tax.` [src](https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart)

Answer (score 0):

The total price increase by 1.21% is due to tax, as mentioned in the comments, which is set in the config file. To have total control of the value returned change set it from the config file.

Path to config file:

```
vendor/gloudemans/shoppingcart/config/cart.php
```

As it is not advised to touch/edit files in the vendor folder, you can run this command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\ShoppingcartServiceProvider" --tag="config"
```

It will Copiy File [/vendor/gloudemans/shoppingcart/config/cart.php] To [/config/cart.php]

Set:  `'tax' => 0,`

> Laravel 5.6

I hope someone will find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

this is because laravel shopping cart add tax to real total of price for that just use Cart::subtotal() this function dont add fax and show you real amount of total prices.